# read data from amazon hbase

Tags: hadoop, hbase, amazon-emr

Can anyone suggest me that whether I can read data from amazon hbase using the org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration and org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTablePool.

We are migrating to Amazon's EMR framework having hbase running on top of it.

The present implementation is based on pure Apache hadoop and hbase distributions. I'm trying to verify that no code changes needed even we migrate to amazon's EMR.

Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

While it should not happen, I would expect the problems and changes related to the nature of EC2 and its networking.
 
HBase relay on Regions able to renew their leases in timely manner. If Region servers are two busy - because of some massive operations over them, they can not do so and get kicked off the cluster. 
In amazon performance of the EC2 instances are much less predictable then in dedicated cluster (unless you use cluster instances), so adjusting timeout parameters and/or nature of your loads might be needed to get cluster to work properly

Comment: Hi David thanks for the comment. Presently I retrieve data using the apache hbase dependency. Parametrized the "hbase.zookeeper.quorum". Retrieve data and render reports.

Can I retrieve data using the same code from HBase in Amazon by changing only the "hbase.zookeeper.quorum". 

Do they have a separate SDK?

Comment: I do not now exactly, but would not expect different versions. Usually Amazon EMR is compatible with apache hadoop (it is actually AFAIK)